# Animation in Libgdx using .pack file

Tags: java, animation, libgdx, texturepacker, texture-atlas

I want to make an animation of player when he 's running.
I put all images into a .pack file using texture packer. And here's my code:

```
TextureAtlas atlas = new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("images1/images.pack"));
private Array<AtlasRegion> textureRegion1 = new Array<AtlasRegion>();
textureRegion1 = atlas.findRegions("rps_man");
animation[0] = new Animation(1/4f, textureRegion1);
TextureRegion currentFrame = animation[0].getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
```

The problem is: my animation run well but it's not smooth. it had "deltils" around the player. Any helps will be appreciated. Thank for reading!

P/s: I had opened .pack file by Notepad and changed `filter: Nearest,Nearest` to `filter: Linear,Linear` but nothing happened.

Comment: Whats "deltis"? Also your animation seems to be 1 frame only. Could you post an image, gif or video of your problem?

Comment: Thank for your attention. "deltis" - I think that the picture is not smooth. I have solve my problem. Libgdx works well. The problem is in photoshop. I tried to cut 1 picture to 4 another pictures in the same size and that 4 pictures are not smooth.
Hope everybody dont have the same mistakes as me. Thank you>:D